# Highlight current page in menu in php-header

Tags: php, html, css

In my php-header document I want to be able to highligt the current page that the user is at, in order to prevent confusion.

The problem is, that I've used an if(isset()) function to hide/showcase the navigation links depending on if the user is logged in or not.

But how do I highlight the pages that the user has clicked on? I guess I have to include some javascript somewhere in the php-tags of the if(isset()) function, then connect it to the active class inside the css, or am I wrong?

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <title>DreamcarZ</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu+Condensed&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="header">

            ​<div class="topnav">
                <div class="logo-container">
                    <h1>Dreamcar<span>Z</span></h1>
                </div>
                    <?php
                        if(isset($_SESSION['userId'])){
                            echo '<a href="index.php">Home</a>
                                <a href="exclusive_cars.php">Collection</a>
                                <a href="om_oss.php">About</a>
                                <a href="#contact">Contact</a>';
                        }
                        else {
                            echo '<a href="index.php">Home</a>
                                <a href="om_oss.php">About</a>
                                <a href="#contact">Contact</a>';
                        }
                    ?>

                <div class="login-container">
                    <?php
                        if(isset($_SESSION['userId'])){
                            echo '<form action="includes/logout.inc.php" method="post">
                            <button type="submit" name="logout-submit">Logout</button>
                            </form>';
                        }
                        else {
                            echo '<form action="includes/login.inc.php" method="post">
                            <input type="text" name="mailuid" placeholder="Username...">
                            <input class="inpt-pwd" type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Password...">
                            <button type="submit" name="login-submit">Login</button>
                            <a class="signup" href="signup.php">Signup</a>
                            </form>';
                        }
                    ?>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a class "active", that will make nav element look to be unique.
Then, create a php variable on each page as a flag value, specific for every single page, then using if clause, assign that 'active' class to nav element.

Please refer to this article for more details:
https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/how-add-active-state-to-the-navigation-menu-with-php/7356

Thanks!

Comment: The thing is, I need to use some kind of script, the teacher has told me. Is it impossible to use a script for the situation I've got there?